# Cannot find the file specified when using subprocess.call('dir', shell=True) in Python

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, path, subprocess

In a 64-bit system with 32 bit python 2.7 installed I am trying to do the following:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)
print p
```

But this gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    p = subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
  WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

If I in the terminal do...

```
dir
```

...it of course prints the present folder content.

I have tried to change the shell parameter to shell=False.

Edit: Actually I cannot call any executable  on the path with `subprocess.call()`. The statement `p = subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)` works fine on another machine and I think that it is related.

If I do

```
 subprocess.call('PATH', shell=True)
```

then I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    subprocess.call('PATH', shell=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
     return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

If I do:

```
import os
print os.curdir
```

then I get

```
.
```

All of the above is executed in the terminal started in Administrator mode.

Comment: `dir` is not an executable, it is a console-only command. Why not use `os.listdir()` instead?

Comment: strange, the code works for me on ubuntu, rhel, win xp, win 7

Comment: Actually I cannot call any executable on the path. The statement `p = subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)` works fine on another machine and I think that it is related. I wanted to simplify my question as much as possible so I only brought up the example with 'dir'. I updated the question...

Comment: Are you running the script from console or from some IDE?

Comment: Also try `subprocess.call('PATH', shell=True)` to see if your path is still OK for shell opened from Python subprocess.

Comment: what is value of `import os; os.curdir` when subprocess fails?

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. I appreciate it!
I have updated my question with the outcome of your ideas.

Comment: Is `subprocess.call('PATH'), shell=True)` a typo? You have excessive `)` in there.

Comment: @Fenikso please add also `os.path.basename('.')`; the reason for those questions is that curdir is the only directory involved in subprocess creation

Comment: @Fenikso: Yes, that was a typo. I edited my question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you may have a problem with your `COMSPEC` environment variable:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['COMSPEC']
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe'
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)

    (normal output here)

>>> os.environ['COMSPEC'] = 'C:\\nonexistent.exe'
>>> subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I discovered this potential issue by digging into `subprocess.py` and looking in the `_execute_child` function, as pointed-to by the traceback.  There, you'll find a block starting with `if shell:` that will search the environment for said variable and use it to create the arguments used to launch the process.

Comment: Nice!
This did it...

The `COMSPEC` variable was set to

`%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;`

Changed it to `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;` and now it is working correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting.  I've never seen a `COMSPEC` set with multiple values—if that is indeed valid, it might be worth filing a bug against `subprocess`.  Glad I could help you!  

Comment: The problem I had appeared after I had installed Windows Management Framework (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595). I don't know the value of the COMSPEC variable before but afterwards it pointed to cmd.exe and powershell.exe. 

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ComSpec the COMSPEC variable should only point to one path? Right? 

Maybe the install process of WMF does somethings strange or do you mean that subprocess should handle multiple paths in the COMSPEC variable?

Comment: I think that—particularly if Microsoft software changes `COMSPEC` in this manner (meaning it's valid)—`subprocess` should be able to deal with it, yeah.  Wikipedia's knowledge would seem to be outdated.

Comment: For me , the values is already os.environ['COMSPEC']
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe'..............and i am running this on jenkins.......Not working for me..........Digging more into it

Answer (score 5):

Before downvote, note that the question was edited after i posted this answer.

I think [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) is more suitable for your case:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir()
['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt', 'DLLs', 'Doc', 'e.txt', 'include', 'Lib', 'libs', 'LICENSE.txt', 'm.txt', 'msvcr100.dll', 'NEWS.txt', 'py.exe', 'python.exe', 'python33.dll', 'pythonw.exe', 'pyw.exe', 'README.txt', 'Scripts', 't.txt', 'tcl', 'Tools']
```

If you want to run it in the command line itself, and just feeling like to call it, you can use `os.sytem`:

```
os.system('dir')
```

This will run the commmand, but it returns `0` and you can't store it.

Comment: Actually I want to call an executable, but that does not work either. I have updated my question...

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else besides me doesn't see this in the (3.4) [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) right away:

> On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies
>   the default shell. The only time you need to specify shell=True on
>   Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the
>   shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch
>   file or console-based executable.
>
> Note Read the [Security Considerations](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) section before using shell=True.

Comment: it should probably be an edit on the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

use Shell= True, It's working for me.