# "The system cannot find the file specified" error in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am using python to solve Captcha level 1 on http://hackthis.co.uk

here is the code

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO
url = "https://www.hackthis.co.uk/levels/captcha/1"
login = "https://www.hackthis.co.uk/?login"
payload = {"username": "user", "password": "pass"}

def solve(captcha):
pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(captcha))
# other code needs to be writted
return "abc";    


s = requests.Session() # Start a session
s.post(login, data=payload) # Login
response = s.get(url).text # Get problem data
captcha = s.get("https://www.hackthis.co.uk/levels/extras/captcha1.php")
captcha = Image.open(StringIO(captcha.content))
captcha.save("E:/captcha1.png")
solution = solve("E:/captcha1.png")
payload = {"answer": solution}
s.post(url, data=payload) # Post data
```

But i am getting an error

Complete log is here http://pastebin.com/7T9aKnPN

If required, here is subprocess.py http://pastebin.com/zmkbhgj6

I tried every other solutions on other forums but none helped

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT : The problem only occurs when i use the pytesseract.image_to_string() method**

Comment: Is that the whole Traceback(error log)?

Comment: nope, just the lines where the error is caught, I can add if you want

Comment: Sure!  Its never bad to have as much info as possible.

Comment: Checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20335954/4725649) answer, did you try that?

Comment: Yup, i did. But nevermind I figured out the solution

Comment: Maybe you should post it just in case someone encounters the same problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem was, tesserect wasn't installed!
i downloaded this Tesserect OCR executables from [the download page](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Downloads)

then added the downloaded directory to `PATH` variable
Installed VC2015 x86 redist (required)
Worked for me :D

Comment: FYI My antivirus (360TS) is detecting the file as a trojan. Dropbox was hacked recently and I heard about zips getting infected.

Comment: UB Mannheim created an installer for Tesseract OCR
Download from http://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.05.00dev.exe 
(its unoffical