# How to use subprocess.Popen with built-in command on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-line, subprocess

In my old python script, I use the following code to show the result for Windows cmd command:

```
print(os.popen("dir c:\\").read())
```

As the python 2.7 document said `os.popen` is obsolete and `subprocess` is recommended. I follow the documentation as:

```
result = subprocess.Popen("dir c:\\").stdout
```

And I got error message:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Can you tell me the correct way to use the `subprocess` module?

Comment: Do note that `dir` on Windows is built into the shell so it is not a standalone executable - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330385/cannot-find-the-file-specified-when-using-subprocess-calldir-shell-true-in

Comment: @metatoaster Thanks. After I read the post, my understanding is that built-in shell command cannot be invoked by `subprocess`. So `os.popen` in this scenario is not 'obsolete'?

Answer (score 5):

You should use call `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=True` as below:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.Popen("dir c:", shell=True,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

output,error = result.communicate()

print (output)
```

[More info on subprocess module.](https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/)

Comment: Using `shell=True` for internal shell commands such as `set` and `dir` is generally a bad idea. The output uses a lossy ANSI encoding. Windows environment variables and filesystem names are UTF-16, so generally internal shell commands should be run with the `/u /c` option to make cmd output UTF-16. The output then has to be decoded as `'utf-16le'`. It can't be done with `shell=True` because `/c /u` is in the wrong order.

Answer (score 2):

This works in Python 3.7:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

args = ["echo", "realtime abc"]
p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True, text=True)

for line in p.stdout:
    print("O=:", line)
```

.

Output:

O=: "realtime abc"