# windows python sub process will not work when using in Othello board game

Tags: python-3.x, windows, subprocess

Still learning python, came across the board game Othello that uses "AI".  [https://www.instructables.com/id/Othello-Artificial-Intelligence/][1]
There are two versions of the game - player on player and player vs AI.
The issue I am having is with the player vs AI, Othello_game.py.   Othello_gui, the player on player works without issue.

The error is:

```
C:\Users\Joe\Documents\OthelloAI-master\OthelloAI-master> python othello_game.py [erika_5.py] [nathan_ai.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "othello_game.py", line 157, in <module>
    player1 = AiPlayerInterface(sys.argv[1],1)
  File "othello_game.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(['python3',filename], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The **init**  is coded as:

```
def __init__(self, filename, color):
    self.color = color
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(['python3',filename], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    name = self.process.stdout.readline().decode("ASCII").strip()
    print("AI introduced itself as: {}".format(name))
    self.name = name
    self.process.stdin.write((str(color)+"\n").encode("ASCII"))
    self.process.stdin.flush()
```

The import statements are:

```
import sys
import subprocess
from threading import Timer
from othello_shared import find_lines, get_possible_moves, play_move, get_score
```

Any help would be appreciated, just learning subprocesses.
[1]: https://www.instructables.com/id/Othello-Artificial-Intelligence/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716557/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-with-built-in-command-on-windows)** by Dinesh Pundkar, the edit is just adding `shell = True`:

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(['python',filename], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```