# Cannot find the file specified when using subprocess.call('dir') in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, subprocess

I am on Windows 10, and I run the following Python file:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("dir")
```

But I get the following error:

```
  File "A:/python-tests/subprocess_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["dir"])

  File "A:\anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:

  File "A:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 210, in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "A:\anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "A:\anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Note that I am only using `dir` as an example here. I actually want to run a more complicated command, but I am getting the same error in that case too.

Note that I am not using `shell=True`, so the answer to this question is not applicable: [Cannot find the file specified when using subprocess.call('dir', shell=True) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20330385/3486684)

This is line 997 of `subprocess.py`:

```
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                                         # no special security
                                         None, None,
                                         int(not close_fds),
                                         creationflags,
                                         env,
                                         os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
                                         startupinfo)
```

When I run the debugger to check out the arguments being passed to CreateProcess, I notice that `executable` is `None`. Is that normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dir is a command implemented in cmd.exe so there is no dir.exe windows executable. You must call the command through cmd.

```
subprocess.call(['cmd', '/c', 'dir'])
```

Answer (score 6):

You ***must*** set `shell=True` when calling `dir`, since `dir` isn't an executable (there's no such thing as dir.exe). `dir` is an [internal command](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/intecomm.htm) that was loaded with cmd.exe.

As you can see from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html):

> On Windows with `shell=True`, the `COMSPEC` environment variable specifies
>   the default shell. The only time you need to specify `shell=True` on
>   Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the
>   shell (e.g. **dir** or copy). You do not need `shell=True` to run a batch
>   file or console-based executable.