# OSError: [WinError 1450] Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service - when running PyWinTrace (python-based ETW solution)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, etw, windowserror

I'm trying to run a Python script based on Pywintrace by FireEye which is a python-based Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) solution. It allows you to specify ETW providers and keywords in order to get real-time output of Windows events printed to your screen.

Initially I was able to run the script ~5 times without a problem, but since then I keep getting the following error:
OSError: [WinError 1450] Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.

I don't know why it stopped working because nothing obvious changed about my environment. Also, I've tried to run the script on two separate machines (Windows 10) as well as on a Windows 7 VM, but I always get the same error.

I found a potential solution for the 1450 error on two separate questions on here, followed the steps for all machines, however, the problem persisted. Those steps included changing the registry entries "PoolUsageMax" and "PagedPoolSize" under memory management.

(The steps followed are from the answers on the following two questions:
[OSError: [WinError 1450] Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service using Selenium in Python through Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752487/oserror-winerror-1450-insufficient-system-resources-exist-to-complete-the-req)

[System error 1450 has occurred. Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845580/system-error-1450-has-occurred-insufficient-system-resources-exist-to-complete))

Any idea how else I can try and fix this error and run the code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: which providers do you try to turn on?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for commenting! I turned on three providers separately (and encountered the same issue each time): Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Registry, Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process, and Windows Kernel Trace.